# Storing sum of a column then equalizing it to another tables column inside of a trigger (Oracle DBMS)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am getting used Oracle SQL Developer but cannot figure it out how to achieve my task.

Here is my code that is not working properly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF AXLE, DIFERANTIAL, SHAFTS 
ON WAREHOUSE_PRODUCTS 
BEGIN
  
    SELECT 
        SUM(Shaft) AS shaftot,
        SUM(AXLE) AS axletot,
        SUM(diferantial) AS diftot 
    FROM 
        warehouse_products;

    UPDATE total_stocks
    SET shafts_stock = shafts_stock + shaftot,
        axle_stock = axle_stock + axletot,
        differential_stock = differential_stock + diftot
    WHERE 
        shafts_stock = shafts_stock 
        AND axle_stock = axle_stock 
        AND diferantial_stock = diferantial_stock;
END;
```

I am trying equalize the sum to another tables column when the specified column affected by insert, update or delete.

Comment: A trigger is not a safe way to maintain summary data like this. If the trigger is disabled, you'll get out of wack and won't be able to fix it. Much better would be to schedule a job that updates the summary. It could also be a materialized view.

Comment: What is the structure of your tables? I sense that the database design presents some issues. Why have the quantities for different items in different columns in a transactional system? Were it a database warehouse, then it would seem OK. Normally you should have in warehouse_products columns like (stock_date date not null, item_id number not null, quantity number not null), the item_id being a foreign key to an items table. Plus, of course, the date on which that quantity is available. And that table should be partitioned by stock_date.

Comment: Generally, for summaries I'd use views or materialized views, not triggers.

Comment: "  https://pasteboard.co/4MEa3eKSvE8B.png  "  this is the ERD diagram for my database.I am trying to create a system that some factories register to and buy some vehicle parts while able to check total stock amount. 
 @BogdanDincescu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a trigger, use a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW total_stocks (shafts_stock, axle_stock, diferantial_stock) AS
  SELECT SUM(Shaft),
         SUM(AXLE),
         SUM(diferantial)
  FROM   warehouse_products;
```

If you must use a trigger then it appears your `total_stocks` table should only have one row and you can combine everything into one `MERGE` statement:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
  AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF AXLE, DIFERANTIAL, SHAFT
  ON WAREHOUSE_PRODUCTS 
BEGIN
  MERGE INTO total_stocks dst
  USING (
    SELECT SUM(Shaft)       AS shafts_stock,
           SUM(AXLE)        AS axle_stock,
           SUM(diferantial) AS differential_stock
    FROM   warehouse_products
  ) src
  ON (1 = 1)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE
    SET shafts_stock      = src.shafts_stock,
        axle_stock        = src.axle_stock,
        diferantial_stock = src.differential_stock
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (shafts_stock, axle_stock, diferantial_stock)
    VALUES (src.shafts_stock, src.axle_stock, src.differential_stock);
END;
/
```

---

As for your code:

- You use `SHAFTS` in the trigger specification and `SHAFT` in the body.
- You have a query that does not have an `INTO` clause.
- You are adding the new total to the old total so your stock levels are going to exponentially increase rather than show the total stock level. The only way the stock level would decrease is if you enter negative values into one of the columns; this seems to be incorrect logic.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/k87w_WaC)